# Why is my green button showing up as white in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a green button that I've generated this css for:

```
.lime_button {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d9fbbe;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d9fbbe;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #d9fbbe;
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #b8e356), color-stop(1, #a5bb52));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #b8e356 5%, #a5bb52 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#b8e356', endColorstr='#a5bb52');
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b8e356 0%, #a5bb52 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#B8E356), to(#A5BB52));
    background-color:#b8356;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    text-indent:0;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    width:300px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #86ae47;
}
.lime_button:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #a5cc52), color-stop(1, #b8e356));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #a5cc52 5%, #b8e356 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a5cc52', endColorstr='#b8e356');
    background-color:#a5cc52;
}
.lime_button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

In **Chrome** it looks fine:

[image: Chrome rendering]

But in **IE10** it comes out white:

[image: IE10 rendering]

Comment: what ie version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be using IE10, which uses `linear-gradient` and not `filter`.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #B8E356,#A5BB52);
```

Should do it.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I'll accept your answer in a few minutes once SO lets me.

Comment: Just as a further note, the Microsoft-specific `filter` values have been [deprecated as of IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to generate gradients with cross browser compatibility.